# Core Data NSTimeInterval using an accessor directly is buggy

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

I'm setting an NSTimeInterval using setValueForKey within an NSManagedObject Subclass, the value gets set correctly, and is also correct when it is retrieved using valueForKey, however, if an accessor is used directly, it returns an incorrect value. Here is a code sample that demonstrates the issue

```
let date = NSDate() //NSTimeIntervalSince1970 = 1447054145.15281
self.setValueForKey(date, "dateLastSynced")

self.valueForKey("dateLastSynced") //= 1447054145.15281
self.dateLastSynced // !!ERROR Incorrect value = 468746945.152815
```

Strangely enough, if the dateLastSynced is converted to an NSDate, everything works perfectly.

Any ideas on whats happening?

Comment: It is of type NSTimeInterval. I've generated the class by checking the use scalar properties while generation. Strangely, if I manually set the type to NSDate, it works but I need to use NSTimeInterval. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A scalar property of type `NSTimeInterval` for a Core Data `Date`
property represents the time in seconds since the reference date
Jan 1, 2001. The Core Data generated accessor methods transparently
convert between `NSTimeInterval` and `NSDate`.

Therefore you *set* a value using the scalar accessor with

```
obj.dateLastSynced = date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

and you *retrieve* the value with

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: obj.dateLastSynced)
```

This gives the same results as the Key-Value Coding methods

```
// Set:
obj.setValueForKey(date, "dateLastSynced")
// Get:
let date = obj.valueForKey("dateLastSynced")
```

Comment: Is this the same behavior if I set the time interval using an accessor but the time interval is since 1970? In other words, is it safe to create NSDate using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate no matter if you set it using KVC or the accessor directly?

Comment: @SalmanHasratKhan: I am not sure if I understand your question, but is does not matter how an `NSDate` object was created. Once it is created, it is an absolute point in time (and *internally* uses the seconds since Jan 1, 2001 as representation).

Comment: What I meant was this, lets say somewhere in my app, I set event.dateLastSynced = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970, and in some other parts of my code I set it using KVC, so is it safe when reconstructing the date anywhere in the app to use NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)?

Comment: @SalmanHasratKhan: `event.dateLastSynced = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` is wrong. You must use `event.dateLastSynced = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` to get consistent results.

Comment: awesome man, I was really pulling my hair out and this seems to work great! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to `self.valueForKey("dateLastSynced")` won't work; it's not an `lvalue`. You need to use `setValueForKey`.

Also, if the `dateLastSynced` is a date property, you cannot assign it a `double` value and expect it to work. Use

```
self.setValue(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: <value>), forKey:"dateLastSynced")
```

Comment: if you notice my code sample, I am using setValueForKey, and also, I am setting a Date not a double, so these are not the issue, any ideas about else is wrong?

Comment: I was referring to what your code looked like before the edit. However, I think Martin R. explained it now.

Comment: my question already had the changes you suggested in your comment before the edit. That's why your answer didn't work but Martins did.