# Storing dates in CoreData - Convert date string to NSTimeInterval?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I want to store dates in my CoreData entity and the model indicates the field should be of NSTimeInterval. Not sure why it's not NSDate though as NSTimeInterval sounds... odd.

From my JSON data source I have the following string: "2016-01-28T23:20:00" and I have no idea how to convert this to a NSTimeInterval. I can convert it to NSDate once I figure out the correct format, but that doesnt do much me much good.

Thanks!

Comment: The string has standard ISO8601 format which is the best choice I suppose

Comment: But how do I convert that into a NSTImeInterval format for storage in Core Data?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33605000/1187415 about the conversion between NSDate and NSTimeInterval for Core Data scalar properties. (But you can also define the managed object property as NSDate.)

Comment: @Zygote You have to convert the string to NSDate anyway... ;-)

Comment: That's true. Any idea how to convert ISO8601 strings to NSDate? :)

Comment: Have you tried to search on SO?

Answer (score 0):

You can store **`NSDate`** in CoreData Directly.

[image]

> **Update**:

If you are using scalar propertie, convert like this:

```
// `NSTimeInterval` -->  `NSDate`: 
var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 123)

// `NSDate` -->  `NSTimeInterval`: 
var timeInterval = date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

Comment: That type will make it a NSTimeInterval as long as you're using scalar properties (as I am doing).